# How is Fragment's Activity reference set?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the Fragment [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/Fragment.java#Fragment.onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29), it says:

```
// Activity this fragment is attached to.
Activity mActivity;
```

I expected this to be set in onAttach(), but according to source it is not:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mCalled = true;
}
```

I can't find a reference in the source to where the Activity reference is set.

Where is it set?

Comment: Line 898 of FragmentManager: 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManager

Comment: @Peregreen should be posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 898 of [FragmentManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManager): manager for fragment's lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

`FragmentManager` handles the reference in `moveToState` when it attaches the `Fragment` to the `Activity`:

```
void moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle,
        boolean keepActive) {
    ...
    if (f.mState < newState) {
    ...
        switch (f.mState) {
            case Fragment.INITIALIZING:
                ...
                f.mActivity = mActivity;
                ...
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An extract of one of my Fragments should help answering this question:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // your activity IS actually given automatically to you as parameter in this overrided method... then do what you want with it...

    String activite =  activity.getClass().getSimpleName();

    if (activite.equals("HomeActivity"))
    {
        STATUS_MODE = "WHITE";
    }
    else if (activite.equals("PhoneActivity"))
    {
        STATUS_MODE = "BLACK";
    }

    // etc. etc.
}
```